# Show Tree component when click on TextBox

Tags: java, gwt

On UI I have a TextBox. I want to show Tree element when user clicks on TextBox. I want to prevent user from direct input text to TextBox (it's value must depend which item  user select  from Tree)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [ReadOnly](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TextBoxBase.html#setReadOnly%28boolean%29) attribute for your textbox, and for your tree widget [addSelectionHandler](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Tree.html#addSelectionHandler%28com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.SelectionHandler%29)

```
tree.addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<TreeItem>() {
        public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<TreeItem> event) {
                  textbox.setText(event.getSelectedItem().getText()); 
        }
  });
```

Comment: thanks, but how to show tree when user clicks on TextBox? Set clickEvent on textbox and then show Tree component near this TextBox (i.e. tree.setPosition(textBox.getX()+50, textBox.getY()+50); tree.show() )?      or exist some more elegant way?

Comment: I think in your case, I would use gwt's Suggest Widget: see demo here http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwSuggestBox

Answer (score 1):

You should use this attribute: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp